# How to install the C library on MinGW?

Tags: c, mingw

How can I install the C library in MinGW?

I always get some error like when I want to run some scripts:

> Cannot find <clang-c/Index.h>  
>   Please ensure libClang is installed

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library is available from the [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) project. [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) is a "a C language family frontend for LLVM." I don't believe they make binary releases yet. So, you would need to check out the code using [Subversion (SVN)](http://subversion.tigris.org/), and then build the library yourself under minGW. Please refer to the "[Getting Started: Building and Running Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#build)" page for detailed instructions.